# Greatest Common Divisor of linear combinations

Tags: number-theory

In my textbook introduction to abstract algebra, it is stated that if $d|n$ and $d|m$ then $d|(xn+ym)$ for all integers $x$ and $y$. Is it true conversely that if $d$ divides $(xn+ym)$ for all integers $x$ and $y$ that  $d|n$ and $d|m$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. 
.
By setting $x=0$, $y= 1$,  $d|xn+ym$ is the same thing as saying that $d|m$.

By setting $x=1$, $y= 0$, $d|xn+ym$ is the same thing as saying that $d|n$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If $d$ divides $n+m$ and $2n+m$ and $n+2m$ then $d|((2n+m)-(n+m))=n$ and $ d|((n+2m)-(n+m))=m.$